# Call one function from another in custom node - NodeRED

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to access the function from another file like below:

**exp1.js**

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
    function expIn(config) { 
        //some code
    }
}
```

I want to access "expIn()" in another file called **exp2.js** how can i achieve this??
please help me.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_modules.asp TLDR: require the module

Comment: module.exports.expIn()? can you access like this?

Comment: I tried that, it did not work if the function is inside the "RED". i can access the other functions but not "expIn". actually this is in node-red custom node.

Comment: You're not showing how you want to call it (which is why I assume the downvotes), but from what you have, you can't access `expIn()` outside of exp1.js.  You would either need to export it (`module.exports = expIn;`) or add it to the outer function's prototype (`this.expIn = function() { ... };`).

Comment: In fact, you can't even access `expIn()` outside of the outer function.

Comment: saiyed No can not

Comment: @c1moore,  it is already in module.exports . and i am calling this as below
     var ex = require('./exp1");
     ex.expIn()

Comment: No it isn't.  You're exporting the outer function.  The inner function cannot be directly accessed.  It's exactly like declaring a local variable in any function (in any language) and expecting to be able to see it outside of the function, it just doesn't work.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As is, you are not exporting `expIn()`.  You are exporting the outer function in which `expIn()` is declared and defined.  `expIn()` is just a local variable and cannot be accessed outside of the anonymous outer function you are actually exporting.  To make it visible to other files, you either have to export it directly or define it *on* the exported function.

You're missing some code, but you have 3 options for accessing `expIn()` outside of `exp1.js`.  First is to export it directly

**exp1.js**

```
module.exports = function expIn(config) {
  // Code...
};
```

**exp2.js**

```
const { expIn } = require('exp1.js');

expIn({/*config*/});
```

Alternatively, you could add `expIn()` to the outer function's prototype.  This is usually done when you want to export a class with several methods attached to it.  You can do this one of 2 ways.  First, the method most similar to what you're already doing is

**exp1.js**

```
module.exports = function ClassName(/*constructor args*/) {
  this.expIn = function expIn(config) {
    // Code...
  };

  // Other initialization...
};
```

Alternatively, you could define `expIn()` more explicitly on the prototype using this method:

**exp1.js**

```
function ClassName(/*constructor args*/) {
  // Initialize class.
}

ClassName.prototype.expIn = function expIn(config) {
  // Code...
};

module.exports = ClassName;
```

Regardless of which of the 2 methods you choose above, you would access it as

```
const ClassName = require('exp1.js');

let classInstance = new ClassName();
classInstance.expIn({/*config options/*});
```

One last method you could use is defining `expIn()` as a static method on the function class.  This would look like:

**exp1.js**

```
function ClassName(/*constructor args*/) {
  // Initialization code...
}

ClassName.expIn = function expIn(config) {
  // Code...
};

module.exports = ClassName;
```

**exp2.js**

```
const ClassName = require('exp1.js');

ClassName.expIn(/*config options*/);
```

Comment: @Vinod What do you mean no luck?  These are all tested.  What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

This i resolved by adding function out side the function(RED):

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
}

function expIn(config) { 
    //some code
}
```

And then exported as normal like :

```
module.exports.expIn = expIn;
```

then it starts working.
I am not sure whether this is a correct method or not but it serves my requirement.